# How can I configure SpringBoot TestContainers to use containerd instead of docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-desktop, testcontainers, containerd

DockerDesktop allows you to enable the use of `containerd`. Doing this appears to disable the docker daemon or prevent TestContainers from accessing the host. 
I would actually like to use `containerd` in my gitlab CI pipelines, but that's a different problem. 
When attempting to run a test that utilizes TestContainers, the following error is observed.

```
Error during callback
com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.DockerException: Status 502: Bad response from Docker engine
```

It appears that you can configure testcontainers using the  `~/.testcontainers.properties` file.

Even the documentation for TestContainers appears to allow you to configure the following 
`docker.client.strategy` where you could pass in a containerd strategy 
`docker.host` to point at a `containerd` api

I think you can tell TestContainers to communicate with the containerd. 
I can't seem to find the right location or figure out where DockerDesktop has containerd running.